# Limiting FREE coupon so it doesn't get passed around!

Tags: cart, coupon-codes, free-gift

We have set up a promo code for a FREE item and FREE shipping that we send to winners of contests or for raffle drawings, etc.  We are concerned that if this promo code gets passed around, we won't be able to control the redemptions.  I have already set it at a max redemption, but is there some other way to ensure that it is only being used once per user - and then not passed on to a friend?

Current rules
- must create an account
- must only have single item in cart
- max redemption per user 1
- max redemption total = 25
- Expires 12/31/17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve that is to give each customer a different coupon code using the coupon generation feature.